# Why are these calculations incorrect

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a pizza order program for my college assignment and i am stuck on calculating the total price of the order, my variables are as follows:

Now for whatever reason the total price that is printed to one of my forms. Using:

```
Form7.lblRecieptDetails.Text = ("Price: " & globalVariables.orderTotal & vbNewLine & "Quantity: " & globalVariables.pizzaCount & vbNewLine & "Toppings :" & globalVariables.toppingCount)
```

is incorrect, but as far as i can see from my eyes i cant see any mistakes so it must be the logic behind the calculation.

```
    Public Shared toppingCount As Double = 0.0
    Public Shared pizzaCount As Double = 0.0
    Public Shared pizzaSize As String = ""
    Public Shared orderDetails As String = ""
    Public Shared pizzabasePrice As Double = 0
    Public Shared toppingPrice As Double = 0
    Public Shared oneTopping As Double = 1.5
    Public Shared twoTopping As Double = 3.0
    Public Shared threeTopping As Double = 4.5
    Public Shared small As Double = 6.0
    Public Shared medium As Double = 8.0
    Public Shared large As Double = 10.0
    Public Shared overallPizzaPrice As Double = 0.0
    Public Shared orderTotal As Double = 0.0
    Public Shared toppingTotal As Double = 0.0
```

Here is the code i used to validate the conditions and calculate the price and everything else: (I am quite new to vb so i understand there will be mistakes and malpractise inside code)

```
 If comboPizzaSize.Text = "Small" Or comboPizzaSize.Text = "small" Then
        If comboToppingCount.Text = "1" Then
            If txtPizzaCount.Text >= 15 Then
                If InputBox("Enter manager password") = "Management" Then
                    globalVariables.pizzaCount = txtPizzaCount.Text
                    globalVariables.pizzabasePrice = globalVariables.small
                    globalVariables.toppingCount = 1
                    globalVariables.orderTotal = globalVariables.oneTopping + globalVariables.pizzabasePrice * globalVariables.pizzaCount
                    If MsgBox("Show Reciept?") = DialogResult.OK Then
                        Me.Hide()
                        Form7.Show()
                        If globalVariables.orderTotal >= 20 Then
                            globalVariables.orderTotal = globalVariables.orderTotal * 0.95
                        ElseIf globalVariables.orderTotal < 20 Then
                            globalVariables.orderTotal = globalVariables.orderTotal
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            ElseIf txtPizzaCount.Text < 15 Then
                globalVariables.pizzaCount = txtPizzaCount.Text
                globalVariables.pizzabasePrice = globalVariables.small
                globalVariables.toppingCount = 1
                globalVariables.orderTotal = globalVariables.toppingTotal + globalVariables.overallPizzaPrice
                If MsgBox("Show Reciept?") = DialogResult.OK Then
                    Me.Hide()
                    Form7.Show()
                    If globalVariables.orderTotal >= 20 Then
                        globalVariables.orderTotal = globalVariables.orderTotal * 0.95
                    ElseIf globalVariables.orderTotal < 20 Then
                        globalVariables.orderTotal = globalVariables.orderTotal
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

Any suggestions? Thanks for any help in advance! :)

Comment: This is a debugging issue and a great chance for you to start to learn that skill (and an essential one at that).  Set a breakpoint and step thru the code as it executes and observe the flow and value of variables to work out what is not working as expected.  [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs) ... [ask] and the [tour] are worthwhile reads as well

Comment: Are you showing the receipt before you calculate the total?

Comment: Please follow standard/proper style guidelines for whatever language you are working in. VB.Net `Public Shared` members should have `PascalCase` identifiers.

Comment: Why have you got a `globalVariables` variable?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of If/Else logic is hard for *anyone* to understand. Better to pull out some sections into "guard clauses", such that you can abort faster, the nesting level is not as deep, there's less repetition, and just plain less code overall:

```
If CInt(txtPizzaCount.Text) >= 15 AndAlso InputBox("Enter manager password") <> "Management" Then Exit Sub
If comboToppingCount.Text <> "1" Then Exit Sub
If comboPizzaSize.Text.Trim().ToLower() <> "small" Then Exit Sub

globalVariables.pizzaCount = CInt(txtPizzaCount.Text)
globalVariables.pizzabasePrice = globalVariables.small
globalVariables.toppingCount = 1
globalVariables.orderTotal = (globalVariables.oneTopping + globalVariables.pizzabasePrice) * globalVariables.pizzaCount

If globalVariables.orderTotal >= 20 Then globalVariables.orderTotal = globalVariables.orderTotal * 0.95

If MsgBox("Show Reciept?") = DialogResult.OK Then
    Form7.ShowDialog()
End If
```

See how much easier it is to follow the logic this way?

While I'm here: Global Variables aren't all that great, either. Better to have a Class defined for a specific order, and pass around a reference to an instance of that class. That might be what `globalVariables` is doing here, but if so that's a poor name.